# How to loop through two ranges in two different excel sheets?

Tags: excel, foreach, vba

So, I have a two tables in two different sheets.

First table is a list of finished goods and its components like so:

A | B |

A | C |

A | D |

B | C |

B | E |

Second table is an extract of the first table, containing only one finished good, like so:

A | B |

A | C |

A | D |

I tried and wrote a code to check, for every line in Table2, if the value in the second column is present in the second column of Table1, and if the value next to it in the first column (of Table1) exists in the second column of Table2, And if so, delete the line (that is being checked) of Table2.

In the example above, it would delete the second line - | A | C | - of Table2, for there is a line | B | C | in Table1 and B is present in the second column of Table2.

Here's my code:

```
    Sub CheckAndDel()
        Dim cll As Range
        Dim rngTmp As Range
        Dim rngMas As Range
        Dim cllToCheck As Range
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim LastRowTmp As Long
        Dim Tmp As Worksheet
        Dim Ms As Worksheet

        Set Tmp = Sheets("Temp")
        Set Ms = Sheets("MasterList")

        LastRowTmp = Range("A" & Tmp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow = Range("A" & Ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


        Set rngTmp = Tmp.Range("B2:B" & LastRowTmp)
        Set rngMas = Ms.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)



        For Each cllToCheck In rngTmp
            For Each cll In rngMas
                If cll.Value = cllToCheck.Value And _
                WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngTmp, Range("A" & cll.Row).Value) > 0 Then
                    Rows(cllToCheck.Row).EntireRow.Delete

            Exit For
                End If
            Next
         Next

    End Sub
```

So far it has been able to detect and delete correctly only one line. Can't really figure out why.
Would it be a good idea (or even possible) to replace the nested loop by an AutoFilter?

Answer (score 0):

you wrote `Exit for` so the first time the condition is true, you exit the loop. Just comment this line and see what happens
**EDIT**
yes, sorry. After a closer look : your have to precize the sheet of your variables `LastRowTmp` and `LastRow`  (otherwise it will take the active sheet) so you have to write :

```
    LastRowTmp = Tmp.Range("A" & Tmp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = Ms.Range("A" & Ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Change also this line to avoid problems :
`Tmp.Rows(cllToCheck.Row).EntireRow.Delete`
I test your code with this changes, it works for me

Comment: I originally wrote the code without that `exit for`, but after deleting the line it would stay in the second loop  and generate an error as what it was looking actually just got deleted. With the `exit for`, at the first encounter of the double condition, the line gets deleted and we go back to the first loop, which supposedly gets us to the next `cllToCheck`.

Comment: what about an error handler? instead of `Exit for` try `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: It gives the same result as the `exit for` solution. In any case, after deleting the row, the code is supposed to get out of the second loop, to implement the first one.

Comment: Alright, that was almost it ! I also changed `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngTmp, Range("A" & cll.Row).Value)` to `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngTmp, Ms.Range("A" & cll.Row).Value)` and that did it ! You saved my life pal ! Thank you so much ! (my vote doesn't count because of my low reputation, but you have my eternal gratitude)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it was more efficient to delete from the last row, so for the sake of free knowledge, here's the working code:

```
    Sub test()


    Dim cll As Range
    Dim rngTmp As Range
    Dim rngMas As Range
    Dim cllToCheck As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRowTmp As Long
    Dim Tmp As Worksheet
    Dim Ms As Worksheet
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim LastRowTst As Long
    Dim i As Long


    Set Tmp = Sheets("Temp")
    Set Ms = Sheets("MasterList")

    Firstrow = Tmp.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    LastRowTst = Tmp.UsedRange.Rows(Tmp.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    LastRowTmp = Tmp.Range("A" & Tmp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = Ms.Range("A" & Ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngTmp = Tmp.Range("B1:B" & LastRowTmp)
    Set rngMas = Ms.Range("B1:B" & LastRow)


    For i = LastRowTst To Firstrow Step -1
         Set cllToCheck = Tmp.Range("B" & i)
        For Each cll In rngMas
            If cll.Value = cllToCheck.Value And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngTmp, Ms.Range("A" & cll.Row).Value) >= 1 Then
                Tmp.Rows(cllToCheck.Row).EntireRow.Delete
               Exit For
               End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```